# Adding kernel32.lib to Eclipse's (with CDT plugins) path for all projects

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have Eclipse Indigo with the CDT plugins installed and am using to develop some C++ applications. Sadly, eclipse requires me to add the following to under projects->property->paths and symbols->libraries and then add 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\kernel32.lib'

After I do this the program compiles fine and all is well, however I was wondering whether there is a way to permanently add this for all projects to save myself time in the long run. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more information or if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered this I shall just say what I did. I added kernel32.lib so that it was accessed by the windows PATH which fixed it for me. However I haven't had this problem on other computers so I'm not sure what caused it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to change the LIB path under *Project Properties> C/C++ Build>Environment* to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Lib**